# How to resize iframe when the parent is a html file but the child is an react app

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api, iframe-resizer, iframe-app

How to resize iframe when the parent is a html file but the child is a react app, and they do not share the same origin. Could someone provide the corresponding code? Thanks in advance.

I tried almost every methods online, including using the iframe resizer, but still cannot find a solution

Comment: This question does not meet [StackOverflow's guidelines for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Iframe-resizer is built to handle this. Did you include the second JS file in your react app.